# Calculate area of a object in cartesian plane

Tags: math, genetic-algorithm, graph-algorithm, cartesian

I wonder if someone can help me to find the area of a 2-D object in Cartesian plane , when we know coordinates of every points. 
Eg : I want to calculate the area of a triangular. A(12,34) B(45,89) C(25,35)

I want a common algorithm to find any 2-D object's area.

Thank you.

Comment: What are the constraints? Are the points always ordered around the object boundary? Is the boundary always closed and the object simply connected (no holes)? Is it always convex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=geometry1&module=Static) you go, uses triangulation. This was literally the top result off Google when I searched "area of polygon given set of points". Please do your research before posting.

Comment: Thank you. I did not use the Polygon keyword that may be the reason not find it.

Answer (score 1):

If your object is a simple polygon, there's no need to triangulate it to compute its area. There's a simple formula that depends only on the coordinates of the vertices. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid

Comment: +1. The area formula may be expressed as a consequence of Green's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Area_Calculation

Comment: @Jason, yes, and it's also a consequence of triangulation.